# Returning the self type in Mustinherit class - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, interface

I have an abstract class as

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericClass

    Public Sub New(Byval x as Integer)
        ' Some code here
    End Sub    

End Class
```

I inherit this class to another class as follows:

```
Public Class SpecificClass
    Inherits GenericClass

    Public Sub New(Byval x as Integer)
        MyBase.New(x)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I want to add a `Shared Function` e.g. `magicFunction` in such a way that when I use it, it should return an object of type `SpecificClass`. What should I do?

I want something like this but it is not allowed in VB.NET

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericClass

    Public Sub New(Byval x as Integer)
        ' Some code here
    End Sub    

    Public Shared Function magicFunction(Byval y as Integer) as GenericClass
        Dim z as Integer
        ' Some code here that will alter the value of z
        Return New GenericClass(z) ' Not allowed in VB.NET -- MustInherit class cannot have new
    End Sub    

End Class
```

Calling the `magicFunction` of the inheriting `SpecificClass` should return an object of `SpecificClass` like this:

```
Public Class ABC

    Public Function myAwesomeFunction as SpecificClass
        Dim objSpecificClass as SpecificClass
        objSpecificClass = SpecificClass.magicFunction(someInteger)
        Return objSpecificClass
    End Sub 

End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructing object of derived type in Base object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086684/constructing-object-of-derived-type-in-base-object)

Comment: You have to use reflection. Something like: `Activator.CreateInstance(Me.GetType)`

Comment: @user1937198 - I read this question and answer before posting my question here. It's not the duplicate of my question. Lemme google about your second suggestion - `Activator.CreateInstance(Me.GetType)`

Comment: Then I think what you what is not possible within the .net type system. Unless you make MagicFunction generic it must return a concrete type which is the same for all derived classes. If you do make it generic you can't constrain it to have a non-deafult constructor.

Comment: Any Workaround? Or I should create the same `magicFunction` in all derived classes with different return values?

Comment: Most of the time you can get away with returning the base class from magicFunction and then casting it to derived in myAwesomeFunction. If you document that it is safe to do the cast on the return its usually not a problem.

Comment: Your `"GenericClass"` is **not** a generic class.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Yes, I know. I have just given it a name GenericClass -- you can name it anything like A, B, C or Bjorn Class... :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericClass(Of T As {GenericClass(Of T)})

    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer)
        ' Some code here
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function magicFunction(ByVal y As Integer) As GenericClass(Of T)
        Dim z As Integer
        ' Some code here that will alter the value of z
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), z)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SpecificClass1
    Inherits GenericClass(Of SpecificClass1)

    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer)
        MyBase.New(x)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SpecificClass2
    Inherits GenericClass(Of SpecificClass2)

    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer)
        MyBase.New(x)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Usage:

```
    Dim a As SpecificClass1 = SpecificClass1.magicFunction(1)
    Dim b As SpecificClass2 = SpecificClass2.magicFunction(2)
```

Comment: Got it. Works fine and exactly what I wanted.